# Laravel - Has Many Through

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to write a DB Query with Laravel 5.3's [Has Many Through option](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

My DB Tables are layed out as follows :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9c9af

The tables are :

companies
company_offers
offers

In my Model I have the following setup :

```
public function offers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Offers', 'App\CompanyOffers',
            'company_offer_id', 'offer_id'
        );
    }
```

When I try to run the following line of code :

```
return $this->whereHas('offers', function($query) use ($offer_id)
        {
            return $query->whereIn('offer_id', $offer_id);
        });
```

I get the Error :

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'offer_id' in where clause
>   is ambiguous

How do I go about correcting this and getting the relationship right?

I need to get the **offer title & offer icon** for my frontend view.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Column 'offer_id' in where clause is ambiguous" basically means the SQL query is dealing with several tables and it doesn't know which table `offer_id` is referring to:

For example the query could be doing something like

```
select offers.* from offers
left join another_table on another_table.field = offers.field
where offer_id = ?
```

Notice that `offer_id` in the above table could refer to a column in `offers` or `another_table`.

What you should do to correct the error is prefix the `offer_id` with a table name. Something like this:

```
return $this->whereHas('offers', function($query) use ($offer_id) {
    return $query->whereIn('other_table.offer_id', $offer_id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathon query is now running, But returning empty data. (Even though there should be a result) Hoping to get an output of the SQL to be able to debug it from there.

Comment: @StuBlackett You can [listen for query events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#listening-for-query-events).

Comment: @StuBlackett You can also use a combination of `\DB::enableQueryLog()` before you execute any queries and `\DB::getQueryLog()` afterwards to see what was executed :)